# Processing: Migrating to 2.0b1 from 1.51 - Issues on video library

Tags: processing

I'm trying to migrate to new processing, as I use often in my life (it's an update, so I'm moving on...).

Here's my setup:

- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Processing 2.0b1 (Launch Program in 32-bit mode)

---

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-11D50b)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

My setup used to work on Processing 1.5 - and all the problems that I'm seeing right now I not had using that release.

First:

Any examples from libraries/video/capture simply don't work. Sometimes it crashes, sometimes it freezes.

The console log after AsciiVideo:

> DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0xc083b7c0,
>   fPowerNotifyPort= 0xc085a0f0 DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort
>   hack = 0xc0809a60, fPowerNotifyPort= 0xc0808080 DVFreeThread -
>   CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0xc08159a0, fPowerNotifyPort=
>   0xc082add0

I use the GSVideo too, and I tried to run the AsciiVideo from there.

The console error:

> GSVideo version: 1.0.0 19200 Invalid memory access of location 0x0
>   eip=0x97cee3ba

and raised an error window

> Process:         java [25673] Path:            /usr/bin/java
>   Identifier:      com.apple.javajdk16.cmd Version:         1.0 (1.0)
>   Code Type:       X86 (Native) Parent Process:  JavaApplicationStub
>   [24849]
>
> PlugIn Path:       /var/folders/*/libjogl_desktop.jnilib PlugIn
>   Identifier: libjogl_desktop.jnilib PlugIn Version:    ??? (???)
>
> Date/Time:       2012-09-05 17:04:08.993 -0300 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.3 (11D50b) Report Version:  9
>
> ...

I work with SimpleOpenNI, GSVideo, GLgraphics, SurfaceMapper... I decided migrate yesterday, to increase performance using the same CPU when I render videos.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to ask this question on the [processing forum](http://forum.processing.org/).
Reason why you get this error is that the video library is rewritten from scratch in Processing 2, and it's based on  GSVideo. Check the video examples in Processing 2.0b3.
Also, SurfaceMapper is currently not working with Processing 2.0, I'll look into that.

Best regards,
Jonas, Ixagon